# PHP Session variables being lost

Tags: php, session

My website has suddenly started losing session variables (like it is timing out within seconds or something).

I have tried creating a test page (PageA.php) which sets a session variable and another test page (PageB.php) which reads the same session variable.  If I first load PageA and then load PageB it echo's the session variable the first few times but if I keep refreshing PageB again the session eventually disappears so it displays nothing.

PageA.php

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['test'] = 'some text';
```

PageB.php

```
session_start();
echo 'session variable result: ' . $_SESSION['test'];
```

The WHM control panel shows the following:

```
          total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:      10105164    9941092     164072          0    1342940    6233408
-/+ buffers/cache:    2364744    7740420
Swap:     12369912     254180   12115732
Total:    22475076   10195272   12279804
```

It seems to me that the site is short of memory.  Is is possible that a memory shortage is causing session variables to be lost?  If so, how can I resolve this?

Comment: Could you possibly show some code?

Comment: I am not sure but I think you will might need to include pageA in pageB .. include("/pageB.php");...

Comment: No, I didn't need to include PageB.  I have updated the question to be clearer.

Comment: Sessions are stored on the disk by default, so i'm not sure the memory would be an issue. If you also echo out session_id() does that change when the value disappears?

Comment: Are you accepting cookies from that domain?

Comment: Could you post the `session.*` ini settings?